# How do you really convert sounds such as voice to text? (the process itself)

Tags: audio, text, voice

Ofcourse, we have APIs available that we can use.

But if you are not going to use an API, can we just attribute a sound to a specific text?

And how can you actually determine that sound is the same with the sound uttered by the user?

What does the computer hear or read when it get sounds? How is it translated to computer language?

Comment: This seems like something a very smart person answered in a white page paper. Consider looking online because this question would take a week to answer explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

> If you are not going to use an API, can we just attribute a sound to a
>   specific text ?

**Yes**, if you're using a **finite** set of available sound datas (files, like wav files) and a dictionary of related text transcription.

```
A.wav <-> "a"
Aaa.wav <-> "aaa"
B.wav <-> "b"
Bee.wav <-> "bee"
...
```

**No**, if you're recording a sound through your microphone or streaming your voice live the same or similar way.

---

> How can you actually determine that sound is the same with the sound
>   uttered by the user ?

That's the reason why your can't provide a lambda sample sound and transcript it to a valid text without using an API. The API is a set of tools that reads a stream of discrete (numeric/binary) values of a sound data, analyze it, and through a massive amount of computation, will **try to** determine what character, word, or "voice convertible to a text data" fits best.

Look :

```
011110110110101010101010001010101101001010101010101010101010...
```

^^ this is the sound data which (coul) looks like this in 2D :

```
 /\
/  \           /
    \_    /\  /
      \  /  \/
       \/
```

... which (vaguely) ressembles the signature for "a" (just an example, actually this is not true). Then, the API outputs "a".

An API also tries to discard datas that has noise signature. Like "pops" and "sssh" artifacts, while keeping them when the currently processed data chunck has the signature of some characters like "p", "s", "t", "tr", "tch"...

---

> What does the computer hear or read when it get sounds ?

The computer doesn't hear nothing. It's just processing the data :

```
011110110110101010101010001010101101001010101010101010101010...
```

> How is it translated to computer language ?

This is already in binary format which is the computer language. When you're talking in a microphone, the hardware device inside that microphone converts the vibrations conveyed by the air into binary data. That data is transferred from the microphone device to the computer through the cable (3.5 jack connected to your computer) Then your sound card does its job.

A sound/video file is already binary data. The computer doesn't convert back the numeric data to audible sound, it's the job of the speaker.

---

In the end :

There is NO any simple manner to get a working `Voice recognition` system (which is the appropriate naming of the thing). Not a single one of the available API out there is 100% perfect and fail safe. But most of them does the job well.

The amount of required knowledge to implement such API would never fit easily in a single topic on SO...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can't vote up yet due to lack of points. Though I really appreciate you for answering my question. Thanks again.

Comment: My answer doesn't deserve an upvote anyway because that doesn't really is the expected answer :) Voice recognition is an entire science. Some API works well in english "tone" for example, but fails 99% of the time when you try "talking" to it "in french". Converting arbitrary sound data to text in one defined language is one topic. Another language is a whole another topic. Converting back is easier, but you need to add voice tone and "context" (you don't say "Okay" the same way if you're happy or angry...) Male and female voices are different... that's why the only path I know so far is API.